# Display grouped table in knockout

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

Below is my view model using knockout.js

```
 viewModel.myArray = ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'Luk', city: 'Warsaw' },
        { name: 'Mark', city: 'London' },
        { name: 'Tom', city: 'London' },
        { name: 'Peter', city: 'Warsaw' },
        { name: 'Paul', city: 'Warsaw' }
    ]);
```

Using `<!-- ko foreach: myArray -->` I can display array in view

But how can I prepare table by grouping array by city like this below using knockout

```
CITY        NAME

[Warsaw]    [Luk, Peter, Paul]

[London]    [Mark, Paul]
```

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this (not tested):

```
viewModel.groupedCities = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        var output = {};
        var arr = viewModel.myArray();
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var item = arr[i];
            output[item.city] = output[item.city] || [];
            output[item.city].push(item.name);
        }

        var keys = Object.keys(output);
        var result = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            result.push({ city: keys[i], names: output[keys[i]]});
        }

        return result;
});
```

Then just a similar `<!-- ko foreach: groupedCities -->` to display them.

Comment: Thanks it help. But i must be output[item.city()] not output[item.city]

Comment: Sure thing. I put that because in your example the properties weren't observables.